# loop on a star rating

Tags: loops, smarty, rating-system

I am trying to loop on dynamic form with star rating. The issue is that this works in the first iteration only. 
Here is my code: (with smarty).

```
<form action="">
            forEach{ $lstCodesNotation as $oneCodeNotation}
            <p>{$oneCodeNotation.description}</p>
            <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
            <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
            <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
            <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
            <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
            <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
            <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
            <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
            <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
            <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
            {/foreach}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach is not write correctly, you have to put it into the `{` like this :

```
{foreach $lstCodesNotation as $oneCodeNotation}
```